# Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no exports

Tags: nfs, ubuntu-14.10

As a note, when setting up the development server on Ubuntu 14.10, I am giving the command:

```
-3000-N200:/# sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

It shows me

`* Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no exports.`

Can any one tall me what does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

It means that you have not added any shares in /etc/exports